# django template boolean variable shows as 0 but is considred True. Why?

Tags: python, django, templates, variables

I have template variables that correctly can be displayed with `{{ myclass.myvariable }}` as either 1 or 0.

But when I use them in the if statement  `{% if myclass.myvariable %}` they always are considered to be True, even when the value is 0.

The variables are 1-character charfield `choices` in my model, stored as 0 or 1, and the django template system chapter-4 claims that:
*'In Python, the empty list ([]), tuple (()), dictionary ({}), string (''), zero (0), and the special object None are False in a Boolean context. Everything else is True.'*

I didn't use `BooleanField` in the model because I also have choice values 2, 3, 4...

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 6):

Because `'0'` (string) is not `0` (integer). `'0'` is non-zero-length string, which means it's `True` in a boolean context. If you store integers, you should be using `IntegerField` or `PositiveIntegerField`, not `CharField`.

Comment: thanks, this put me on track (I must have been sleeping). Also needed to drop the db table and syncdb. Finally I did switch to booleans because django admin then displays the user-preferred tickboxes instead of drop-down list. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting your values from a `CharField` then it is `'0'`, not `0`

```
>>> True if 0 else False
False
>>> True if '0' else False
True
```

Comment: ...or `bool(0)` vs. `bool('0')`.

Answer (score 0):

They are treated as strings (`'0'` string and `'1'` string, not `0` integer and `1` integer).

If you go to your command-line Python and call `bool(0)` or `bool(False)`, you will get `False`, but if you call `bool('0')`, you will get `True`.

Comment: `bool(value)` will do, there is no need for double negation in Python.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus: Yup, you are right - I have updated my response.